# What is the default values for Django fields?

Tags: python, django-models

According to [Django Model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/) documentation, `null` and `blank` options are default to `False`. So what would be the default value for an `IntegerField` if I don't provide it explicitly? Also, `CharField` and others will be helpful.

Comment: I don't have a django install at hand here and I won't bother going thru the source code to find out but IIRC, if you don't provide a default the default value for any field will be `None`, which translates to SQL `NULL` - which of course should raise an exception at the database level (on any proper SQL database at least) if you leave `null=False` in your field's definition. But you'd better try and find out by yourself (it's a five minutes affair if you already have a django project at hand).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see in Field methods

```
def has_default(self):
    """
    Returns a boolean of whether this field has a default value.
    """
    return self.default is not NOT_PROVIDED

def get_default(self):
    """
    Returns the default value for this field.
    """
    if self.has_default():
        if callable(self.default):
            return self.default()
        return force_text(self.default, strings_only=True)
    if (not self.empty_strings_allowed or (self.null and
               not connection.features.interprets_empty_strings_as_nulls)):
        return None
    return ""
```

It would be `None` for `IntegerField` because of `empty_strings_allowed = False`, and after that on creating or saving you will get `ValidationError()` because value is in not `int()`

as for CharField you will get "" empty string because `CharField` has `empty_strings_allowed = True`

P.S. avoid using `null=True` on `CharField` and `TextField` as of in Django documentaion says

> Avoid using null on string-based fields such as CharField and
>   TextField because empty string values will always be stored as empty
>   strings, not as NULL. If a string-based field has null=True, that
>   means it has two possible values for “no data”: NULL, and the empty
>   string. In most cases, it’s redundant to have two possible values for
>   “no data;” the Django convention is to use the empty string, not NULL.